# Program to find sum of differences of max and min element of every subarray using divide and conquer

Tags: divide-and-conquer

for example:
Given array: 1,4,1
The result should be 9. How can I write a divide and conquer algorithm for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please read [ask] to understand how to ask properly a question and what information are expected for this question to be answered, then [edit] your question to add the information.